# With beamer, prevent animation from restarting on 2-step slide

Tags: beamer, animations

I have a slide with an animation with autoplay on the top and two graphs at the bottom. The graphs appear in two stages. At the moment, the animation restart when I go to the second step, how I can prevent that? To be clearer, I would like the animation to stay on its last frame (instead of restarting) as I advance to the second part of the slide.

The code so far:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Example 1}
\begin{center}
\includemovie[autoplay,mouse]{10em}{7em}{Pics/bar_cubic.avi}
\end{center}

\hfill

\begin{columns}
   \hfill
   \centering
   \column{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics<1>[width=1.\textwidth]{Pics/reaction_bar_quad.pdf}
   \includegraphics<2>[width=1.\textwidth]{Pics/reaction_bar.pdf}
   \hfill
   \centering
   \column{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics<1>[width=1.\textwidth]{Pics/energy_bar_quad.pdf}
   \includegraphics<2>[width=1.\textwidth]{Pics/energy_bar.pdf}
   \hfill
\end{columns}
} %%%
```

Comment: I think this is in principle very difficult (each slide is a page in its own). However, I guess you can emulate it by making the other pictures to an animation (albeit, you have to either _time_ perfectly or press them to run them).

Comment: Maybe you could put your animation on a `\only<1>{}` environment and put a picture of the same size (eg: the last frame of the animation) in a `\only<2>{}` to replace the animation... Or even better perhaps, put the animation again in a `\only<2>{}` but without autoplay

Comment: I tried to use the option 'startat' in `\includemovie`like this, but it was unsuccessful:
`\only<1>{\includemovie[autoplay,mouse]{10em}{7em}{Pics/bar_cubic.avi}}`
`\only<2>{\includemovie[startat=time:6,autoplay,mouse]{10em}{7em}{Pics/bar_cubic.avi}}`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. (At least not in any simple way: see below.)

Each slide generated by `beamer` (or any other route to a PDF presentation from TeX) is a separate page in the PDF file. As such, the animations on different slides are separate as far as the viewer application is concerned. Thus they will always restart when you advance a page.

I guess there are a couple of possible 'get outs'. First, modern PDFs support 'optional content groups (OCGs) when allow variability of the material on a page. However, `beamer` doesn't generate those and indeed I'm not sure they would work for the case here. The second possible get out is to use JavaScript to tie things together. This is viewer-dependent, again not done by `beamer` and has a reputation for being not 100% reliable. Certainly neither of these approaches are available 'built in' to `beamer` (you'd have to code yourself) and I'm not even sure either would work!